# SQL - Adding IF condition to my stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure where I **Increment** the **sub_days** value **daily**,

I want to add a condition where

> if  **sub_days = 30**  then   **sub_months=sub_months+1** and
>   **sub_days=0**

How to add this condition to my stored procedure?

My SP:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users_With_Month] 
     @ID bigint


    AS
    BEGIN

       update Subscribers_Profile 
       set Sub_Updated = GETDATE() , sub_days = sub_days+1
       where sub_ID = @ID


**add condition here**

    END
```

Comment: MSDN docs for [IF..THEN..ELSE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)

Comment: Obviously not all months have 30 days though? Without knowing any better, I'd suggest using an actual date to increment those days with for example DATEADD(DAY, 1, @DATEPARAM), which will automatically increment the actual date with months and years where applicable, so you could then parse the actual day, month and year from that date.

Comment: @Kahn Except this application considers all subscribing months to be 30 DAYS ONLY. So I have to increment this myself. :)

Comment: Ok, added an answer for that then, if I understood correctly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users_With_Month] 
@ID bigint

AS
BEGIN

   update Subscribers_Profile 
   set Sub_Updated = GETDATE()
      , sub_days = CASE WHEN sub_days+1 >= 30 THEN 0 ELSE sub_days+1 END
      , sub_months = CASE WHEN sub_days+1 >= 30 THEN sub_months+1 ELSE sub_months END
   where sub_ID = @ID

END
```

And in case you have NULLs in sub_months you can just use ISNULL in the case, like:

```
... THEN ISNULL(sub_months,0)+1 ELSE sub_months END ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users_With_Month] @ID bigint AS BEGIN
UPDATE Subscribers_Profile
SET Sub_Updated = GETDATE() ,
                  sub_days = sub_days+1
WHERE sub_ID = @ID 

  DECLARE  @sub_days  INT;
  SET @sub_days  = (SELECT sub_days FROM dbo.Subscribers_Profile WHERE sub_ID = @ID);
IF @sub_days =30 

BEGIN
  UPDATE Subscribers_Profile
  SET sub_months = sub_months +1 ,
      sub_days=0 WHERE sub_ID = @ID ;

 END 

ELSE 


END
```

Comment: Thats not going to work. Where exactly is your stored proc getting the sub_days value to perform it's calculation?

Comment: no problem. If you want to cut the additional select, you could also use the output clause: `Update X Set Y = @days + 1 output Inserted.Y Where ID = @ID`

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

THIS MIGHT BE YOUR LOOKING FOR BASE ON YOUR SAMPLE CODE

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users_With_Month] 
 @ID bigint
AS
BEGIN
Declare @Sub_Days int
Declare @sub_months int

SELECT @Sub_Days = sub_days + 1, @sub_months = sub_months
FROM Subscribers_Profile
WHERE sub_ID = @ID

If @Sub_Days >= 30
BEGIN
    SET @Sub_Days = 0;
    SET @sub_months = @sub_months + 1
END

UPDATE Subscribers_Profile 
    SET Sub_Updated = GETDATE(),
    sub_months = @sub_months,
    sub_days=@Sub_Days
WHERE sub_ID = @ID

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Update_Users_With_Month] @ID bigint AS BEGIN 
 SET Sub_Updated = GETDATE() ,
                 sub_days = sub_days+1
  WHERE sub_ID = @ID 

  DECLARE  @sub_days  INT;
    SET @sub_days  = (SELECT sub_days FROM dbo.Subscribers_Profile WHERE sub_ID = @ID);
     IF @sub_days =30 

  BEGIN
      UPDATE Subscribers_Profile
      SET sub_months = sub_months +1 ,
      sub_days=0 WHERE sub_ID = @ID ;

   END 

  ELSE 


    END
```

Comment: Thanks very nice Mr.Senthamizh